# Find homedirectory absolute path and work with that path

Tags: powershell, active-directory, home-directory

I am fairly new to Powershell and have been googling for a solution for weeks now.
I am looking for a way to find the absolute path of a homedirectory and work with that path.
We have homedirectories on several servers. These homedirs are not always on the same drive, some servers use the D and others the E drive for this (I am not allowed to change this).
When users leave company I have to move their homedir to a DeletedUsers folder.
AD only shows the relative path of the homedir, not the absolute path.
I am finding a way to do a search on the server (I can get the servername from the relative path) for the homedir folder.

```
$Homedirectory = get-aduser $Username -properties Homedirectory |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Homedirectory
$Server = $Homedirectory.split('\')[2]
```

This is what I have to search for all drives on the server.

```
$AllDrives = get-PSdrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
$NameToFind = "*$Username$*"
$Homedirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path $AllDrives -Filter $username -Recurse -Directory
```

It does not give me an error, but it also does not give me a path.

Hope someone can shed some light on this, thank you!

Comment: How do you have only a relative path in your AD? Or do you mean you need to have the absolute path for the share on the according servers? Have you tried to use [Get-SmbShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbshare?view=windowsserver2022-ps) on the according servers?

Comment: I have no idea how this  works. As I mentioned, I am pretty new to Powershell

Comment: I assume it's not the relative path you have in you AD it is the path in the form `\\Server\Share`, right? If that's the case you have to extract the servername and use this to query the accoring server for the absolute path of the SMB share.

Comment: Thanks. Never new this was a thing. Will give this a try.